# Printing model count in view (MVC)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I would like to put some statistics right in front of my site, like:

```
# jobs/index.html.haml
.panel
    .panel-heading
        %h4 Statistics
    .panel-body
        .col-md-9.col-xs-9
            %h5.pull-left Users
        .col-md-3.col-xs-3
            %h5.pull-right= @usercount

        .col-md-9.col-xs-9
            %h5.pull-left Companies
        .col-md-3.col-xs-3
            %h5.pull-right= @companycount

        .col-md-9.col-xs-9
            %h5.pull-left Categories
        .col-md-3.col-xs-3
            %h5.pull-right= @categorycount

        .col-md-9.col-xs-9
            %h5.pull-left Total offers gathered
        .col-md-3.col-xs-3
            %h5.pull-right= @jobcount
```

At the moment these variables are all set in controller:

```
# controller: jobs, action: index
@jobcount = Job.count
@usercount = User.count
@categorycount = Category.count
@companycount = Job.distinct.count('company')
```

but I believe that's the worst way to do this in **MVC**. Can anybody tell me **how it should be done**?

Comment: use draper gem for decorator on model view please see https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper a good rails cast on draper

Comment: well, I understand you feel bad about violating REST logic but if you need additional data in the jobs index, just load it... :)

Comment: yea, I feel like I am doing it completely against MVC rules, that's why I wanna learn the best practices how to load data like this, bro

Comment: This being a stats view, you can probably create a DB view, or a DB function that returns all those stats at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this style:

    `@statistics = {
      job_count: Job.count,
      user_count: User.count,
      category_count: Category.count,
      company_count: Job.distinct.count('company')
    }`

Comment: Now I've got only one variable, well, but I'm afraid that's still not the best practice to import data from any model into one specific controller, don't you think so?

Comment: It depends, if you just need this information, why bother creating another object for this? Just load it up!

Comment: Actually I find your way the best, I've asked some more people and it is not like violating MVC rules, meanwhile generating decorators is pretty too much for this purpose. Thanks for your opinion, @Frozenna!

Answer (score 1):

If we're taking [the rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) as a reference, it says that we should avoid [sharing more than two instance variables in a controller](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#controllers).

Ways to circumvent that are decorators (as mentioned in the comments). A popular library providing such functionality is draper or just some plain ruby object you wrote yourself.